# Kong Regex for Replacing String in URI

Tags: kong, kong-plugin, kong-ingress, konga

I am facing a particular issue with the "strip_path" feature available

```
**Service Name**: application-svc
**Service Path**: /application

**Route for Service**: application-route
**Route Path**: /
**Strip_Path**: True

**Backend API**: /openapi

**Expected**:
calls made to www.xyz.com/applications/openapi will transform the url
from:  www.xyz.com/applications/openapi
to: www.xyz.com/openapi

**Actual Result**:
calls made to www.xyz.com/applications/openapi end up with  www.xyz.com/applicationsapplications/openapi
```

Can someone please help??

Answer (score 0):

Strip_Path is in relation to Route Path, not Route and Service Path.

To solve your problem use the following:

```
**Service Name**: application-svc
**Service Path**: 

**Route for Service**: application-route
**Route Path**: /applications
**Strip_Path**: True

**Backend API**: /openapi

**Expected**:
calls made to www.xyz.com/applications/openapi will transform the url
from:  www.xyz.com/applications/openapi
to: www.xyz.com/openapi

**Actual Result**:
calls made to www.xyz.com/applications/openapi end up with
www.xyz.com/openapi
```